# GRAILS, Classes not loading

Tags: grails

I tried to create a plugin and installed it in my project. When I tried to run my app its giving an error. I uninstalled the plugin, but still getting the following error.

```
[localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.ContextLoader  - 
Context initialization failed
Message: Error creating bean with name 
'grailsApplication' defined in ServletContext 
resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: 
Invocation of init method failed; nested 
exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsConfigurationException: 
Class not found loading Grails application: jsonapi.JsonController
```

Please help me to get my app back to working

Comment: Have you tried cleaning?

Comment: Yes, But still the same

Comment: Is `JsonController` part of the plugin which you refer from the app?

Comment: was it working before you added your plugin?

Comment: Yes its working before. And yes JsonController (import grails.converters.JSON) is part of the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you actually uninstalled your plugin. 
grails list-plugins and 
grails uninstall-plugin  are your friends